# Delegate when constraints updated

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I am facing an issue while using storyboard auto layout with UIScrollView. I am updating a constraint of a UIScrollView, and after that setting the content size of scrollview. But UIScrollView constraint takes a bit of time to update and initially UIScrollView is not able to scroll because of more height than a view. I can not change the current implementation.

Is there any way, notification or any delegate method to check that the constraints are updated, so that I can do further changes?

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *scrollViewHieghtConstraint;

self.scrollViewHieghtConstraint.constant = 500;
[self.scrollView updateConstraints];

[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 1000)];
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `- (void)updateViewConstraints` selector of `UIViewController`.

You can also use `- (void)updateConstraints` selector of `UIView` if you have extended said view.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) One thing i like to add is. We must have to call [super updateViewConstraints] in this method otherwise it will crash.

Comment: Most methods you call from the framework should use the call to super. It is really important if you have to deal with `UIViews` because the classes you extend from will have effects on the layout, thats also why it will crash if you do not because the `NSConstraints` will be unsatisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call -updateConstraints directly. You have to mark the view's constraints as dirty and iOS will call that method on the next update cycle.

On a UIViewController's implementation, add this when you need the constraint to change:

```
self.scrollViewHieghtConstraint.constant = 500;
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

I'm assuming that UIScrollView is a subview of the UIViewController's view. If it's not, then call -setNeedsLayout on the scrollview's parent view.

And if you need to know when the subviews are already on their right place, you have a callback for UIViewController, called -viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Yes UIScrollView is a subview of UIViewController's view.

Comment: `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` callback generally called before constraints added to `UIViewController`s view. If you are using constraint based layout and want to update subviews' constraints depending to `UIViewController` constraints you should always use `-updateViewConstraint` callback.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not correct. -viewDidLayoutSubviews is called after the constraints are calculated and everything is in place inside the view. Yes, -updateViewConstraints is for changing the constraints if you want more control over what the system gives you, but it's not a method to be called by you. You have to mark the layout as dirty, and the system calls it for you.

Comment: @galrito By "use" I always meant to subclass of course. You should not call `-updateConstraints` on any object. Also I think `-setNeedsLayout` is an overkill for constraint based layout, you can call `-setNeedsUpdateConstraints`.

Comment: @Cemal No, overkill is calling -setNeedsUpdateConstraints when you already made the changes to the constraints. By doing that, you are telling iOS to recalculate all constraints when it's not needed.
Auto-Layout consists of three steps: 1. Update Constraints; 2. Layout; 3. Display. By calling -setNeedsLayout, you are jumping the first step and making the process a lot faster, because, in this case, you already know that you don't need to update any constraints, you only need to change the view's frames.